# Disperse Markers in ArcPy or ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, modelbuilder

So I have a set of around 100 clusters that are all contained in a different shapefile. I want to use the disperse markers tool on all of them, but I don't want to go in an individually use the tool on each cluster (Probably going to have to do the same process on larger sets later).

I tried using python and ModelBuilder, but the problem I keep running into is setting the representation of the layer. This is easily done through the UI by right clicking on the feature and then clicking on **Convert Symbology to Representation**, but this process seems much more difficult in python and ModelBuilder. I tried using variations of the representation tool (add representation, calculate representation, set layer representation).

I'm not too sure if there is a tool that can do this or some python code that may be able to do this better?